# Como desenhar uma imagem a partir do zero usando o método drawimage ou drawRGB em J2ME no WTK da Sun?

Tags: java, imagem, j2me

Será que o método `drawimage` ou `drawRGB` pode criar do zero qualquer imagem ou gráfico ou ícone em formato png para jogos j2me ou não? Será que eu posso desenhar uma imagem usando o método `drawimage` ou `drawRGB` sem precisar carregar uma imagem de um local específico?

Eu não quero carregar uma imagem existente, mas sim desenhar ela do zero. Ou seja, redesenhar a imagem pixel a pixel.

Alguém poderia me demonstrar uma forma de fazer isso? Obrigado.

Comment: Por favor respondem !!!!!!!!!